# Split using some value as delimiter and move the the next line (python)

Tags: python, split, line

I have a file with very very long string and need to split it using specific value for example #@#@ as my delimiter. After this value I need to move to the new line. I am having trouble to move to the next line and write to a new file.

Answer (score 0):

I dont know if i understand good a problem, but just try to replace #@#@ to #@#@\n. It will cut your text on lines after your delimiter

```
s.replace("#@#@", "#@#@\n" )
```

and then write it to file

Answer (score 0):

Open your file, read your big string, break it into a list and them write the new file line by line:

```
file = "old_file.txt"
delimiter = "#@#@"

with open(file) as src:
    long_str = src.read()

long_str = long_str.replace(delimiter, f"{delimiter}\n")

# If you don't want to keep the delimiter
broken_str = long_str.split(delimiter)

new_file = "new_file.txt"

with open(new_file, 'w') as dst:
    dst.writelines(broken_str)
```

This will lose the delimiter on the new file